# Conditional Operator without evaluating twice?

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

Say I have the following:

```
MyDate = 
  (db.MyTables.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MyID == idToFind).DateValue == DateTime.MinValue) 
    ? DateTime.Now 
    : db.MyTables.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MyID == idToFind).DateValue
```

Is there any way to do this without running that LINQ query twice?
I cannot run it first into a temp variable because this query is itself part of a bigger LINQ query.

Comment: Yes. Try not to duplicate code. This causes more work and is prone to bugs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I cannot run it first into a temp variable because this query is
>   itself part of a bigger LINQ query.

You can use a `let` assignment within your query (or alternatively a projection that includes a helper field if you are using lambda syntax - that's what it gets compiled down to anyway):

```
var query = from foo in db.Bar
            let bar = db.MyTables.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MyID == idToFind).DateValue
            select  new 
            {
               MyDate = bar == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Now : bar
            }
```

Comment: That's fantastic. I never knew 'let' existed. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

```
var dateValue = db.MyTables.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MyID == idToFind).DateValue;

return dateValue == DateTime.MinValue ? DateTime.Now : dateValue;
```

Now, when you're saying that the value can't be stuffed into a temp value, what do you mean? The above code certainly looks to be able to converted to that pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate once and assign to a variable - use the variable in your conditional:

```
var item = db.MyTables.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MyID == idToFind);

MyDate = (item.DateValue == DateTime.MinValue) 
    ? DateTime.Now 
    : item.DateValue
```

Or:

```
var theDate = db.MyTables.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MyID == idToFind).DateValue;

MyDate = (theDate == DateTime.MinValue) 
    ? DateTime.Now 
    : theDate
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a temporary variable, declare it but assign it inside that expression.
Lots of code might make it hard to read in some situations, but at least reduces duplication.

```
MyDate = 
  (temp = db.MyTables.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MyID == idToFind).DateValue) == DateTime.MinValue) 
    ? DateTime.Now 
    : temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ's `let` statement

```
from a in someSource
let d = db.MyTables.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MyID == a.idToFind).DateValue
select (d == DateTime.MinValue) ? DateTime.Now : d;
```